# Simplify the following algebraic expression by combining indices

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is my first post on this site. So I hope it is ok.

I want to simplify the following term.

$${ \left(\frac{T^4}{T^{2.8}} \cdot  \frac{Y^6}{Y^3} \cdot  \frac{T^3}{T^{-5}}\right)}^4$$

I have watched loads of YouTube videos but still don't really understand.

I came up with this answer : $T^{8.1142856}\cdot {Y^8}$

Is this correct? And could anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: You should accept the answer which helps you by clicking at the right check mark on that answer. It is the most elegant way of saying thanks to answerer and you will get 2 reputations too :-) cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might help

$$1. ~~a^m \times a^n=a^{m+n}$$

$$2. ~~\frac{a^{m}}{a^n}=a^{m-n}$$

$$3. ~~\left(a^m\right)^n=a^{m\times n}$$

(Here $a >0$)

Comment: Thank you. From what you commented I came up with T = 36.8. Y = 12. Is this correct? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @Liam I think you mean $$T^{36.8} \times Y^{12}$$. If you mean this, then yes, it is correct.

Comment: Yes I mean That. Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of this expression, what you want to do is simplify the internal expression first in order to exponentiate, so as to not have large numbers floating in arithmetic operations, which can be a hassle and leads to errors frequently.

Taking each of the individual quotients and subtracting the bottom exponent from the top, the exponents of $T, Y$ and $T$ fall out as $1.2, 3$ and $8$ respectively. Due to the associative property, the exponents of $T$ may combine and thus result as $9.2$.

Now that you have reduced the internal expression to simplest form, being $T^{9.2}\cdot Y^3$, you can exponentiate the entire expression by multiplying each exponent by $4$.

Finally, the output becomes $T^{36.8}\cdot Y^{12}$, I hope this explanation helps.